# Is there a way to generate output as a list in C++?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++. I am trying to generate different permutations of a string as shown in the code below. However, due to my need for certain downstream processes where member functions of a list will fit the most, I am wondering if there is a possibility of generating all the permutations as different elements in the list. Thereafter, I can use the list with other member functions. I have been trying and so far, I have only managed to assign each permutation individually to the list and output it with every iteration of the loop. However, I want to generate only one list at the end of all the iterations. I am aware that I need to take it out of the loops and I have tried but I was unable to call on outputlist outside of the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <list
using namespace std;

void createList(string item) {
     list<string> outputlist; 
     outputlist.push_back(item);
     cout << "The output list is: " << endl; 
          for(list<string>::iterator iter=outputlist.begin(); iter!=outputlist.end(); iter++) {
          cout << *iter << endl; 
          }
} 

void permutations(string str, int i, int n) {
     if(i == n-1) {
       createList(str);
     } 
     for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
         swap(str[i], str[j]); 
         permutations(str, i+1, n); 
         swap(str[i], str[j]); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use references, or classes? This can be done with references, or with classes.

Comment: `outputlist` is declared inside of `createList`, and thus (as you have discovered) is local to it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you very much for your comment! I have a basic understanding of what referencing a variable means and looks like but I am unsure how to apply it here. As for classes, may I ask do you perhaps suggest grouping these functions as a public class?

Comment: @ScottHunter thank you very much for your comment! It helps me to solidify my understanding of my error, much appreciated!

Comment: Pass a reference to your list into `permutations()`, and have the reference forwarded recursively. Move `push_back()` into `permutations()`. Mission accomplished, wasn't that easy?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I see. I did not think of using a reference that way but it is definitely useful in this context and I believe the other author also used a similar approach below. Thank you very much for your kind explanation and help in this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is local, and you never return it.

In your case taking by output parameter allow easy modification inside recursive function:

```
void permutations(std::string str, int i, int n, std::list<std::string>& output) {
     if(i == n-1) {
       output.push_back(str);
     }
     for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
         std::swap(str[i], str[j]); 
         permutations(str, i+1, n, output); 
         std::swap(str[i], str[j]); 
     }
}
```

To simplify the call, I suggest to add

```
std::list<std::string> permutations(const std::string& str) {
    std::list<std::string> res;

    permutations(str, 0, str.size(), res);
    return res;
}
```

and so your `main` might be:

```
int main()
{
    for (const auto& s : permutations("hello world")) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fe804160d0c6553)

Notice that std provide [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation), so I will do:

```
std::vector<std::string> permutations(std::string s)
{
    std::vector<std::string> res;

    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    do {
        res.push_back(s);
    } while (std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));

    return res;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eedce18579a12246)

Notice the difference of results (except the order), `std::next_permutation` doesn't have duplicate output when input has duplicate letters.

Comment: thank you very much for typing out such a detailed answer to my post! I would like to clarify some areas, if you don't mind, for my learning. What does not returning the list do? In addition, what is the importance of putting a & before the list name 'output'? After trying to modify my recursive parameters as what you have suggested, I could not call on my function `permutations(str, 0, str.size(), output)`. May I know what I should correct instead? Lastly, thank you for introducing me to `std::next_permutation`! I noticed you used vectors, can this be done with lists too in C++?

Comment: if you don't return local variable, it stay local, and ends at end of function, and cannot be seen from outside. in our case, if we return the list, we would have to concatenate all list from recursive call (in the loop). Taking by reference (`&`) simplify code here. if you omit `&`, you pass by value, so the copy stay only inside the function (similar problem than we have before). `std::vector` should be the default choice for container, but you can use `std::list` instead.

Comment: @JessicaJiaying: Demo added to show how to call them.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much for taking the time to type out all the details including the demo and helping me greatly in my learning! I have tried the code and even managed to output the total number of permutations as well. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @JessicaJiaying: Notice that as permutation number grows fast, it is generally better to do the job (as printing) immediately for each permutation instead of collecting those permutations in container for later use.

Comment: I see. I will keep that in mind if I need to use the code for more permutations, thank you very much for the tip!